# JSP post XML data to server

Tags: java, xml, jsp

How can I post XML data from JSP page to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP is just a view technology providing a template to write HTML/CSS/JS in and the ability to interact with backend Java code using EL and taglibs like JSTL.

To send some information to the server side in HTML, you'd like to use a form with an input element and a submit button. E.g.

```
<form action="servlet" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="xml">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The webbrowser will send the input values as request parameter to the server side. You'd like to create a servlet wherein you just grab the request parameter as follows in the `doPost()` method:

```
String xml = request.getParameter("xml");
```

Instead of a small input field, you can also use a textarea:

```
    <textarea name="xml"></textarea>
```

Grabbing the request parameter value in the servlet happens the same way.

If you *actually* wanted to **upload** a XML file, then you rather need an `<input type="file">`:

```
<form action="servlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="xml">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Obtaining the uploaded file is a whole story apart. The JSP/Servlet API prior to version 3.0 doesn't offer builtin facilities for this. The file (and other kinds of fields) isn't available as request parameter. You'd like to use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). You can find usage explanation and code examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/upload-big-file-to-servlet/2424824#2424824).

#### See also:

- [HTML forms tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)
- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)