# how to upload xml and then parse it using java

Tags: xml, parsing, jsp, upload

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to upload a XML file using Java. I have a JSP page and am trying to parse it so the text-boxes on the JSP page can be loaded correctly. This is pretty much an import feature. I know how to generally parse a XML file, but I'm not sure how to go about uploading it so I can parse it. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP post XML data to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295930/jsp-post-xml-data-to-server)

Comment: @balusc - looked like a nice answer you gave on other question, so +1 there

Answer (score 1):

[Apache commons fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) is a component you can integrate to get the file uploaded. Then, as you say, you know what to do.